# Unable to dynamically import TensorFlow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I am trying to dynamically import TensorFlow.js using the `import` function. However, I always receive a `TypeError: t is undefined` error. The following code is a simple HTML file which recreates the error.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
import("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js")
  .then(tf => { console.log(tf); });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I also desire to dynamically create the code that will use the TensorFlow.js library. Any help on how to dynamically import TensorFlow.js in the browser and run dynamically created code that uses its functions is much appreciated. Below is code that acts similarly to my end goal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
let code = `import("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js").then(tf => {

// Define a model for linear regression.
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));

model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

// Generate some synthetic data for training.
const xs = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 5, 7], [4, 1]);

// Train the model using the data.
model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 10}).then(() => {
model.predict(tf.tensor2d([5], [1, 1])).print();
// Open the browser devtools to see the output
});

});
`;

let script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
document.body.appendChild(script);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could very well just add the script element dynamically ?

```
const el = document.createElement('script')
el.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js";
el.onload = (() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.innerHTML = "console.log(tf)";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
})();
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

**Alternative**

you could also append the script earlier, but do not execute until tf is loaded

example is

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = `
  function someDependentCode() { 
    console.log(tf);
    // put all dependent code string here
  }
`;
document.body.appendChild(script); //code is added but not called

const el = document.createElement('script')
el.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js";
el.onload = someDependentCode(); //dependent code can now execute
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Is there a way for the `theFunctionHere` to contain dynamically created code that depends on TensorFlow.js in this solution?

Comment: Yeah. Since tensorflow has loaded you can have code that depends on it.

Comment: Okay. Yeah replacing `thenFunctionHere()` with `eval(dynamicallyGeneratedCode)` works.

Comment: For my curiosity, is there any way to dynamically create a second script element, whose textContent depends on your `el` script? Cause creating the following script afterwards does not work and throws a `ReferenceError: tf is not defined`.

Comment: ```let script = document.createElement("script"); script.textContent = "console.log(tf)"; document.body.appendChild(script);```

Comment: I’m a little confused by your comment. In my case the function, let’s say foobar() will not exist until after the page loads. It will not be anywhere in the static JavaScript code. Do your previous 3 comments still apply? If so, can you explain a little more?

Comment: can you explain your scenario better? Where is this code being generated and coming from?

Comment: The JavaScript code exists in Markdown files (mixed with Markdown text). The goal is to create a Firefox web extension that will dynamically load the Markdown file when visited in the browser, parse and separate the Markdown text and JavaScript code, and then convert the Markdown text to HTML, render it on the page and then execute the JavaScript code pulled from the Markdown file. Thus the JavaScript code in the Markdown file does not exist until after the page loads.

Comment: assuming the javascript code is proper, you can write 
var script123 = document.createElement('script'); script123.innerHTML = "your javascript code string here"; document.body.appendChild(script123) . using script123 just so that you dont overwrite any other variable. use proper naming conventions.

Comment: The above 3 lines of code should be called instead of the thenFunctionHere

Comment: I have updated the answer above. Please update the question too so that it may be useful for future reference as others wont be reading the comments

Comment: In my case, a reference error is thrown when trying to use any third party library loaded in a previous dynamically created script as I explained in comments 4 and 5.

Comment: can you confirm if you have used the same code as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Ahh oh so I should create the new script inside the onload function. I’ll try that out.

Comment: yeah, that is because it is only after the onload that the value is available, another alternative is to write the code as a separate function and call it onLoad() . I will update the answer for that case too

Comment: I had forgot to call the function in onload updated the answer again. do check

Comment: Thank you so much the first option works perfectly.